# How to compress a foreman.cif file which is in its raw format to any .avi/.mpg/.mp4 format

Tags: video-processing

I have downloaded the .cif format videos and now I have to learn how to compress this video for eg 'foreman.cif' to any other format for eg : .avi/.mpg/.mp4 video?

Any matlab help would be appreciable.

Awaiting the response

Comment: What exactly do you to use Matlab for?

Comment: I meant to ask that ..how to use .cif file format to compress it to a .mp4 or /mpg file?

Comment: Have you tried any tools like Handbrake?

Comment: Thank you Leppie. I was not talking about a software which converts one video to another. How exactly can we fed a .cif video to a matlab program...any code sample ...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this code writes CIF in Matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8983-splitmix-yuv-component-in-cif-420-video-file/content/func_YUV_mix.m
So it should be easy to convert it to reader.